# How Can I avoid Blank pages from SSRS PDF files?

Tags: reporting-services

Am creating One report project. Where am having one normal report named (Report1.rdl) and one sub report named (Report2.rdl).

Am calling the main report in side the sub report five times by passing values through parameters. So I have five parameters as well. when parameter value is 0 then respective report will not show in the sub report. But thing is that when am doing this am getting blank pages at the end and between the pages as well.

So can You please help me With this. I have already checked with the sizes and clear designing of the main report.

Comment: Also i have tried with 'ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace=TRUE' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are 'calling' the reports in the incorrect order.

Main reports 'call' sub reports, not the the way you have it at the moment. Therefore you need to embed the sub-report inside the Main report. As detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159837%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> "A subreport is a report item that displays another report inside the
>   body of a main report. Conceptually, a subreport is similar to a frame
>   in a Web page. It is used to embed a report within a report."